# Is there a way to hide passwords from the ToC from WFS layers in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, geoserver, wfs

So I have layers in WFS format being served from Geoserver for different users to be used in QGIS.

Problem is that every single layer shows the login and password for geoserver in 2 places:

- the table of contents when moused over
- in properties > general > layer source as shown below

[image]

Is there a way to block it from showing?

Comment: which security system do you have set up on GeoServer?

Comment: @iant do you mean security settings? Just the default ones

Comment: So just basic security?

Comment: @iant not sure what you mean, I tried checking "Encrypt web admin URL parameters" but nothing happened

Comment: GeoServer can be set up to use many types of security system - see http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/security/tutorials/index.html for some examples

Comment: @iant I just tried following all the steps in http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/security/tutorials/digest/index.html but it didn't do anything